# TOMCAT+SPNEGO how to limit area again user groups

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, single-sign-on, spnego

I am new to Tomcat SSO, and now the SPNEGO is working fine for automatically sign on. But my app need to check the group of the user. Can SPNEGO do that? I put these under the SPNEGO filter, but will break the automatic sign on

```
  <security-constraint>
      <display-name>Protected Area</display-name>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>AuthorisedUser</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>    

  <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Example Windows Authentication Area</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
  <role-name>AuthorisedUser</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basic is not SPNEGO. Why did you define an auth-method? SPNEGO is a mere authentication mech just like Basic or Digest. Authorization is performed by your realm. So SPNEGO is here out of scope.